# Can I extract only the body text of an eml file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, email-parsing

I need to extract just the text in the body of an eml file but my code keeps giving me some code text and the folders that exist in Outlook. I am working with Python 2.7 and BeautifulSoup.
My code is:

```
import email
from email import message_from_file
import os
import bs4 as bs
import re

# Path to directory where attachments will be stored:
path = "D:\Python"

# To have attachments extracted into memory, change behaviour of 2 following functions:

def file_exists (f):
    """Checks whether extracted file was extracted before."""
    return os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, f))

def save_file (fn, cont):
    """Saves cont to a file fn"""
    file = open(os.path.join(path, fn), "wb")
    file.write(cont)
    file.close()

def construct_name (id, fn):
    """Constructs a file name out of messages ID and packed file name"""
    id = id.split(".")
    id = id[0]+id[1]
    return id+"."+fn

def disqo (s):
    """Removes double or single quotations."""
    s = s.strip()
    if s.startswith("'") and s.endswith("'"): return s[1:-1]
    if s.startswith('"') and s.endswith('"'): return s[1:-1]
    return s

def disgra (s):
    """Removes < and > from HTML-like tag or e-mail address or e-mail ID."""
    s = s.strip()
    if s.startswith("<") and s.endswith(">"): return s[1:-1]
    return s

def pullout (m, key):
    """Extracts content from an e-mail message.
    This works for multipart and nested multipart messages too.
    m   -- email.Message() or mailbox.Message()
    key -- Initial message ID (some string)
    Returns tuple(Text, Html, Files, Parts)
    Text  -- All text from all parts.
    Html  -- All HTMLs from all parts
    Files -- Dictionary mapping extracted file to message ID it belongs to.
    Parts -- Number of parts in original message.
    """
    Html = ""
    Text = ""
    Files = {}
    Parts = 0
    if not m.is_multipart():
        if m.get_filename(): # It's an attachment
            fn = m.get_filename()
            cfn = construct_name(key, fn)
            Files[fn] = (cfn, None)
            if file_exists(cfn): return Text, Html, Files, 1
            save_file(cfn, m.get_payload(decode=True))
            return Text, Html, Files, 1
        # Not an attachment!
        # See where this belongs. Text, Html or some other data:
        cp = m.get_content_type()
        if cp=="text/plain": Text += m.get_payload(decode=True)
        elif cp=="text/html": Html += m.get_payload(decode=True)
        else:
            # Something else!
            # Extract a message ID and a file name if there is one:
            # This is some packed file and name is contained in content-type header
            # instead of content-disposition header explicitly
            cp = m.get("content-type")
            try: id = disgra(m.get("content-id"))
            except: id = None
            # Find file name:
            o = cp.find("name=")
            if o==-1: return Text, Html, Files, 1
            ox = cp.find(";", o)
            if ox==-1: ox = None
            o += 5; fn = cp[o:ox]
            fn = disqo(fn)
            cfn = construct_name(key, fn)
            Files[fn] = (cfn, id)
            if file_exists(cfn): return Text, Html, Files, 1
            save_file(cfn, m.get_payload(decode=True))
        return Text, Html, Files, 1
    # This IS a multipart message.
    # So, we iterate over it and call pullout() recursively for each part.
    y = 0
    while 1:
        # If we cannot get the payload, it means we hit the end:
        try:
            pl = m.get_payload(y)
        except: break
        # pl is a new Message object which goes back to pullout
        t, h, f, p = pullout(pl, key)
        Text += t; Html += h; Files.update(f); Parts += p
        y += 1
    return Text, Html, Files, Parts

def extract (msgfile, key):
    """Extracts all data from e-mail, including From, To, etc., and returns it as a dictionary.
    msgfile -- A file-like readable object
    key     -- Some ID string for that particular Message. Can be a file name or anything.
    Returns dict()
    Keys: from, to, subject, date, text, html, parts[, files]
    Key files will be present only when message contained binary files.
    For more see __doc__ for pullout() and caption() functions.
    """
    m = message_from_file(msgfile)
    From, To, Subject, Date, Body = caption(m)
    Text, Html, Files, Parts = pullout(m, key)
    Text = Text.strip(); Html = Html.strip()
    msg = {"subject": Subject, "from": From, "to": To, "date": Date, "body": Body,
        "text": Text, "html": Html, "parts": Parts}
    if Files: msg["files"] = Files
    return msg

def caption (origin):
    """Extracts: To, From, Subject and Date from email.Message() or mailbox.Message()
    origin -- Message() object
    Returns tuple(From, To, Subject, Date)
    If message doesn't contain one/more of them, the empty strings will be returned.
    """
    Date = ""
    if origin.has_key("date"): Date = origin["date"].strip()
    From = ""
    if origin.has_key("from"): From = origin["from"].strip()
    To = ""
    if origin.has_key("to"): To = origin["to"].strip()
    Subject = ""
    if origin.has_key("subject"): Subject = origin["subject"].strip()
    if origin.has_key("body"): To = origin["body"].strip()
    Body = ""
    return From, To, Subject, Date, Body
```

and these are my tries for bs:

```
"""
# Usage:
f = open("e.eml", "rb")
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(f,'lxml')
for url in soup.find_all('body'):
    print url.get('href')
f.close()
"""

f = open("e.eml", "rb")
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(f,'lxml')
for body in soup.find_all('p'):
    text = soup.get_text()
    print text
f.close()


"""def cleanhtml(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
    return cleantext
    
f = open("e.eml", "rb")
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(f,'lxml')
for goal in soup.find_all():
    body = soup.find('body')
    the_contents_of_body_without_body_tags = body.findChildren()
    soup.get_text()
    print the_contents_of_body_without_body_tags
f.close()
"""

"""f = open("e.eml", "rb")
message = email.message_from_file(open('e.eml'))
text = Text.text(message)
#print extract(f,f.name)
f.close()
"""
```

The goal is to have the text written in an eml file printed and then write it on a csv file that will rank it as spam or ham.
The only thing remains is to isolate the text body somehow.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you link to a pastebin of an example .eml file?

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: Yeah you can download a sample .eml file from my drive here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1loy0PdV5zu1AVEFAYJsA5GuBj5XAEwV5/view?usp=sharing